# Write makefile for program using OpenCV, link error

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile to compile some code using OpenCV, here is my makefile:

```
    CC=g++
    CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I/home/me/OpenCV2/opencv-2.4.11/include
    LIBS=-L/home/me/OpenCV2/opencv-2.4.11/build/lib/ -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_contrib

    all: code

    code: codeUtils.o codeLibs.o code.o 
        $(CC) $(LIBS) codeUtils.o codeLibs.o code.o -o code

   code.o:code.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)  code.cpp

    codeUtils.o: codeUtils.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)  codeUtils.cpp

codeLibs.o: codeLibs.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)  codeLibs.cpp
```

However, it generates a lot 'undefined reference' errors, which part in makefile is wrong? Thanks

errors look like this:

```
    codeUtils.o: In function `getGradients(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)':
    codeUtils.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
    codeUtils.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
    codeUtils.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `cv::Sobel(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, int, int, double, double, int)'
    codeUtils.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
    codeUtils.cpp:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
    codeUtils.cpp:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `cv::Sobel(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, int, int, double, double, int)'
   codeUtils.o: In function `getHOGatKey(cv::KeyPoint const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, int, int, cv::Mat&)':
   codeUtils.cpp:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)'
```

Comment: which kind of errors? could you post them somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your libraries aren't quite right.  `pkg-config` might help you out here:

```
    CFLAGS=-c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
    LIBS=`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

If for some reason opencv isn't called that, you might find it in `$ pkg-config --list-all` or `$ locate opencv.pc` to find the file (I'm not quite sure what it will do with a local installation.)  You can set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` if you find the `.pc` file and want to include it in `pkg-config`'s search path.

Comment: If you run pkg-config with --libs, what do you get?  Something reasonable?